# Как задать размер изображения на кнопке по размеру текста на кнопке?

Tags: android, button, drawable

Я динамически создаю кнопки. Необходимо динамически добавить изображение слева от текста кнопки, как это делает android:drawableLeft в файле разметки. При этом размер изображения (высота картинки), независимо от исходных размеров резурса drawable, не должен превышать размер (высоту) текста кнопки. Как это проще всего реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по разному. Попробуйте вот такой [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089598/3212712):

```
buttonView.leftDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon, R.dimen.icon_size)

// Button extends TextView
fun TextView.leftDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0, @DimenRes sizeRes: Int) {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id)
    val size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(sizeRes)
    drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, size, size)
    this.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null)
}
```